# Refresh parent page with tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using an page with 4 tabs. Those are labeled #tab1/#tab2/#tab3/#tab4. I have an edit function which opens a new window. If that window is closed through clicking submit or just closing it the parent window should be refreshed. Well this works now but it always refreshes the first tab. Could you tell me how to adjust my code so it only takes an specific tab?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        $(this).next("div").stop('true','true').slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
window.onunload = refreshParent;
function refreshParent() {
    window.opener.location.reload();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution will be to set the paren't url to something like `http://origilal.url#tab3` and the reload() like you do.

Afterwards, in your init js function, parse the window.location to check what tab is mentioned in the url, and select it.

Comment: Thanks for replying. The tabs are in a ul and are li's itself.      <ul class='tabs'>
    <li><a href='#tab1'>...</a></li></ul>  So i have to get like tabs.#tab1?

Comment: Then your code seems to refresh all tabs, because it will reload the full parent page. What you may want is to update specific parts of the parent page, or a more simple solution will be to set the paren't url to something like `http://origilal.url#tab3` and the reload() like you do. Afterwards, in your init js function, parse the window.location to check what tab is mentioned in the url, and select it.

Comment: I fixed it by adding window.opener.location.href='home.php#tab1' in front of the window.opener.location.reload(); Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Edited the answer to be more specific to your case ;)